# HTML page loads different first and second time (Google Chrome)

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I have an HTML page that loads one way the first time you load it and another way the second time. This is reproducible using Chrome in private mode (because it clears the cache each time).

FIRST TIME:
[image]

SECOND (AND LATER) TIME:
[image]

I haven't seen a problem like this before, and am having trouble searching other complaints on this. Any advice on where to start investigating?

## EDITS

Thanks for all the feedback. Just to clarify a few things. The CSS is standard Bootstrap 3.0 only, there is no other styling or CSS. The URL is https://www.acls.net/index-exp120.php and this is Chrome Private mode with all extensions disabled. I only see this issue in Chrome, have updated title to reflect that.

Comment: that could just be the browser..have you checked you css for that part of the site?

Comment: you mentioned the word later, is there some CSS not loading, possibly being blocked by some script loading? this would then have finished loading and be cached the second time?

Comment: What if you disable the cache via Chrome's dev tools settings? Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: Are you using definition lists in your markup by chance? If so, I've run into this issue before also.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't reproduce even in private mode on any browser. Check that maybe some plugin tries to interfere.

Comment: OK @MarioW suggested the fix. For posterity, the broken version of the code is at http://pastebin.com/Wj8YMgXc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - the issue depends on multiple things

- only might happen with an empty cache
- depends on the loading speed of font-awesome & bootsrap - if they load faster than your logo or not...

So while running Chrome in Incognito Mode and reloading again and again eventually I could reproduce the issue.

You cannot easily fix the loading race condition but fixing your css should work :

1. add class `pull-left` to your logo
2. clear the floated area by applying class `clearfix` to the page-header
3. Its not necessary but good choice, add `width` & `height` to your logo image so it doesn't pop in once loaded

So here it is:

```
<div class="page-header clearfix">
    <a href="/" class="logo pull-left"">
        <img src="images/logo.png" height="62" width="232" alt="">
    </a>
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I am now using pull-left and clearfix on this page. I have submitted the broken page to Google Chrome team and archived it at http://pastebin.com/Wj8YMgXc

Comment: I was having a very weird issue which lead me here where only the second time a page was loaded it showed up properly on a Lumia 720. When reloading the page, or rotating the cellphone, it showed up properly. Your answer made me look into Font Awesome somehow conflicting with Bootstrap. Surely enough, disabling Font Awesome resolved the issue. I then moved the `<link>` import of Font Awesome _after_ Bootstrap, which also resolved the issue. Do you know where I can find out more about the exact reason behind this? I would imagine perhaps the order of CSS loading matters.

Answer (score 0):

Some main issues to look into.
Browser size. 
Is it wider at one point than the other?

It's obviously within the same browser but just in case, I would test this in multiple browsers, because you do want your code to be cross compatible.

To me it looks like a width problem.

Perhaps you have a #login div, or some oddly named, at the top right that contains that content and floats it, and being that the content is not responsive, but the div itself is.  When the div shrinks a little the content itself doesn't and pushes the rest of the content down.